# Adding a button to bottom of UITableViewController with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to have an add button that animates to the bottom of my UITableView. I know this can be done if I put the tableView in a UIViewController and leave a bit of room at the bottom, but I want the add button to be "floating" at the bottom of the tableView, on top of the cells.

I have tried this:

```
var addButton: UIButton!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, -44, 88, 88))
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "addList"), forState: .Normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("addList:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.tableView.addSubview(btn)
    addButton = btn
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 50, 88, 88)
        self.addButton = btn
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

However this doesn't work and no buttons are added.
I have tried to put the button in the middle of the screen and that didn't work either.
How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have made a small mistake.Try this CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height-44, 88, 88) instead

Comment: @sanman that didn't work either

Comment: you are try button in footer part in tableview.

Comment: first try to set background color of btn for checking btn is present or not. Your code looks correct. Your code will add btn on top of uitableview not on bottom you have to change your button frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by adding a cell inside the tableview.
put a button inside in it.

code :

inside viewcontroller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NextButtonTableViewCell")! as! NextButtonTableViewCell

    return header.contentView
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}
```

/////////////

```
class NextButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var _btnNext: UIButton! // set outlet
```

}